# How to create many Bokeh figures with multiprocessing?

Tags: bokeh

I would like to speed up figure generation in Bokeh by multiprocessing:

```
jobs = []
for label in list(peakLabels):  
    args = {'data': rt_proj_data[label],
                    'label': label,
                    'tools': tools,
                    'colors': itertools.cycle(palette),
                    'files': files,
                    'highlight': highlight}
    jobs.append(args)

pool = Pool(processes=cpu_count())
m = Manager()
q = m.Queue()
plots = pool.map_async(plot_peaks_parallel, jobs)
pool.close()
pool.join()      

def plot_peaks_parallel(args):
    data = args['data']
    label = args['label']
    colors = args['colors']
    tools = args['tools']
    files = args['files']
    highlight = args['highlight']

    p = figure(title=f'Peak: {label}', 
               x_axis_label='Retention Time', 
               y_axis_label='Intensity',
               tools=tools)
    ...
    return p
```

Though I ran into this error:

> MaybeEncodingError: Error sending result: '[Figure(id='1078', ...)]'. Reason: 'PicklingError("Can't pickle  at 0x7fc7df0c0ea0>: attribute lookup ColumnDataSource. on bokeh.models.sources failed")'

Can I do something to the object `p`, so that it becomes pickleable?

Answer (score 0):

Individual Bokeh objects are not serializable in isolation, including with `pickle`. The smallest meaningful unit of serialization in Bokeh is the `Document`, which is a specific collection of Bokeh objects guaranteed to be complete with respect to following references. However, I would be surprised if `pickle` works with `Document` either (AFAIK you are the first person to ask about it since the project started, it's never been a priority, or even looked into that I know of). Instead, I would suggest if you want to do something like this, to use Bokeh's own JSON serialization functions, such as [`json_item`](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/embed.html#json-items):

```
# python code
p_serialized = json.dumps(json_item(p))
```

This will properly serialize `p` in the context of the `Document` it is a part of. Then you can pass this to your page templates to display with the Bokeh JS embed API:

```
# javascript code
p = JSON.parse(p_serialized);
Bokeh.embed.embed_item(p, "mydiv")
```